# Send request to backend as user not server apache2 on js website

Tags: angular, spring-boot, apache2

I need to send request to backend as user, not as a server from my website hosted on apache2.
Request that go from my javascript website have ip of server on which it's hosted itself, not user IP.
The case why I need it, is because I need to collect user ip when they send particular request from my website.

I am confused, because I thought javascript is used on user browser, and request will be send as user

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem.
I can get real request IP in 2 ways.

1. By enabling remoteip module in apache2.
   a2enmod remoteip.
   Then I have ip in header x-forwarded for.
2. I am using cloudflare, and its also appending real IP in header.
   Name of this header is cf-connecting-ip